# How to correctly deprecate API endpoint in go / goa framework?

Tags: go

What is the correct way of deprecating endpoint in go / goa framework e.g.:

```
a.Action("foo", func() {
    a.Routing(
        a.PATCH("/foo"),
    )
    a.Description("Test endpoint")
    a.Response(d.OK, func() {
        a.Media(someTestMediaType)
    })
    a.Response(d.Accepted, func() {
        a.Media(someTestMediaType)
    })
    a.Response(d.BadRequest, JSONAPIErrors)
    a.Response(d.InternalServerError, JSONAPIErrors)
})
```

In java / spring world I would just put `@Deprecated` annotation on controller method and if swagger is in place it would also mark it is deprecated so that this would be reflected both in code & UI:

[image]

Wondering what is go / goa equivalent for this ?

Comment: It seems to not be possible at this point. `Deprecated` field of path operations in `gen_swagger` are [hardcoded to false](https://github.com/goadesign/goa/blob/563a70bfd6948d71bcf09bc105aee5ec745c0409/goagen/gen_swagger/swagger.go#L949).

Comment: @fips thanks for your response. But is there any go / goa lang facility to warn that code is deprecated even not taking swagger into account. The best I can come up with is just adding "Deprecated" to action name / description + adding "Deprecated: " to the doc comment

Comment: Yes, from the [golang blog](https://blog.golang.org/godoc-documenting-go-code) "To signal that an identifier should not be used, add a paragraph to its doc comment that begins with "Deprecated:" followed by some information about the deprecation". Here's an [example](https://golang.org/src/net/http/transport.go#L107).

Comment: @flips sounds good, thanks for clarifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Deprecated: Use strings.HasPrefix instead.
```

will work.

[image]